# How to sort Japanese characters with emacs?

Tags: sorting, emacs, cjk, kana

I'd like to know if there is a way to sort a column of words written in hiragana, according to the [Gojūon ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goj%C5%ABon), preferably using emacs. 
Is there an easy way to do this, like assigning custom numerical values to the characters, and sorting accordingly?

Comment: You tried it, and what happened?

Answer (score 2):

If it is limited to Hiragana only, `sort-columns` should work, as Hiragana are already in Gojūon order within Unicode.